# Hide column in Form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, form, hide-elements

I am using SharePoint Online and trying to make a column (My Column) invisible in the NewForm.aspx using jQuery (which I have no experience in). Here is the code I have tried by inserting into a Script Editor web part with no success.

Can anyone comment on how I might get this working?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$("nobr:contains('My Column')").closest('tr').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your code get execute first and after which the dom is rendering.
You can wrap your code in document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nobr:contains('My Column')").closest('tr').hide();
});
```